# Calendar waking computer from sleep

Tags: windows-10, sleep, calendar

Windows 10 keeps waking my computer from sleep over every notification.

How can I prevent this from happening, while I still want to see the notifications when I turn on the computer?

Comment: I have the same problem, haven't found a solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

When I had this problem I went into Task Scheduler (type `task sched` in the windows search and it will come up) and found the Calendar. I unchecked the option "wake computer from sleep". While this meant I didn't get all the notifications when I woke the computer up again, it was better than nothing.